# Trying to convert a column of number grades to letter grades within a function

Tags: r

I am trying to write a grade calculation function. The function is supposed to:

- Alert the user if the read in file type is not a data frame or matrix
- Assign 0 to any empty values in the data frame or matrix
- Calculate the final grade percentage by finding the weighted average of 8 homeworks (each worth 5 points), 5 quizzes (each worth 10 points), and  3 exams (each worth 100 points)
- Convert the final grades to letter grades, with any grades in the range [90,100] being an A, [80,90) being a B, [70,80) being a C, [60,70) being a D, and [0,60) being an F.
- Print messages allerting the user as to how the grade was calculated
- Print all columns of the original matrix or data frame, with columns for the final number and final letter grades appended to the end (I only need to print the data for the first 3 students).

I've written the following code:

```
grades = read.table('http://pengstats.macssa.com/download/rcc/grades.csv',
              header=T, sep=',', fill=TRUE)

grade_cal = function (graded, hw_w, quiz_w, exam_w){

if(!is.matrix(grades) & !is.data.frame(grades)){
stop('Grades must be in a data frame or a matrix.')
  }

grades[is.na(grades)] = 0;

grades$Final=100*hw_w*rowSums(grades[,3:10])/(5*8)+
100*quiz_w*rowSums(grades[,11:15])/(10*5)+
100*exam_w*3*rowSums(grades[,16:18])/(100*3)


grades$Letter = {
  if (grades$Final >=90) {
grade = "A"
}
  else if (grades$Final >=80){
grade = "B"
  }
  else if(grades$Final >=70){
grade = "C"
  }
  else if(grades$Final >=60){
grade = "D"
  }
  else {grade = "F"}
}

message("There are 8 HWs, 4 Quizzes and 3 Exams Calculated for each person.")
message("Weights are",  hw_w, ",", quiz_w, ",", exam_w, "respectively for HW, Quiz and Exam.")

grades[1:3,]
}

grade_cal(graded= grades, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
```

This code currently returns the following "Error in `[.data.frame`(grades, Final) : object 'Final' not found". When I remove the section to try to calculate the letter grade, my code runs so that is where the error is (I only included the rest of the code to give some background). How can I fix the letter calculation section to make it run? Thanks

Edit: Upon changing grades[Final] to grades$Final, I now get the following warning: "In if (grades$Final >= 90) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: you can't write `grades[Final]`, why not use `grades$Final` like when you defined it.

Comment: I thought that grades$Final would create a new column in the data frame grades which was called Final, so I figured that grades[Final] would be the proper way to reference the column (sorry, my R knowledge is still quite limited). Fixed it!

Comment: `if`doesn't work with vectors and `grades$Final` is one. It will therefore only take the first value of the vector. To work with a vector you need `ifelse` as suggested by Floo0

Comment: On a general note: Maybe some people downvoted because they felt like we should not do someone else's homework (this comes from R. Peng's coursera course). I agree, but I think this question demonstrates enough effort to count as a proper SO question. If I'm mistaken about downvoter's motives, please correct me here in the comments - this would also be helpful for the OP to improve her future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Haboryme, `if else` as you use it only works for single values, and not for vectors. Sticking with your (rather cumbersome) requirement of using the if-else logic, this might do it:

```
grades$Letter = ifelse(grades$Final >=90, "A",
                   ifelse(grades$Final >=80, "B",
                          ifelse(grades$Final >=70, "C", 
                                 ifelse(grades$Final >=60, "D", "F"))))
```

Alternatively, you could write a `for` loop (as an example of bad, bad coding):

```
grades$Letter = ""
for (i in seq_along(grades$Final)) {
   print(grades$Final[i])
   grades$Letter[i] = {
      if (grades$Final[i] >=90) {
         "A"
      }
      else if (grades$Final[i] >=80){
         "B"
      }
      else if(grades$Final[i] >=70){
         "C"
      }
      else if(grades$Final[i] >=60){
         "D"
      }
      else {"F"}
   }
}
```

This second option is especially bad because it makes you read a lot of code before you can understand what is going on, and because there are already some nice vectorized solutions in R already as pointed by others in this thread.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I was just looking into how to use ifelse statements for multiple different elses. I did consider the for loop, but figured that there had to be at least SOME better way to do it.

Comment: @Caitlin I forget to add condition for "C" but you get the point (added now). You are right in your intuition: *usually* (not always) a `for` loop can be replaced by something much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace your `grades$Letter` call with

```
  grades$Letter = cut(grades$Final, 
                      breaks = c(0,60,70,80,90, 100), 
                      labels = c("F", "D", "E", "B", "A"),
                      right = FALSE, 
                      include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Which gives you

```
  Session UserID HW1 HW2 HW3 HW4 HW5 HW6 HW7 HW8 Q1 Q2 Q3  Q4 Q5 Exam1 Exam2 Exam3 Final Letter
1       A      1 5.0 5.0 5.0 4.8   5 4.8 4.9   5 10 10  9 7.0 10  90.5  92.5  90.5 92.85      A
2       A      2 4.8 4.9 4.6 5.0   5 4.6 5.0   5 10  7  6 7.5  9  63.0  45.5  37.0 64.35      D
3       A      3 4.8 4.9 4.4 0.0   0 0.0 4.9   5  8  7  5 0.0  9   0.0   0.0   0.0 23.60      F
```

If you want to use your `if ... else` structure you could use `ifelse` which is vectorised for this kind of tasks

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of the cut function. I do think that I am supposed to stick with the if else structure for this part though since a later question asks if there are any other ways that it could be done without using an if else structure.

Comment: Nice. If `breaks` and `labels` are in the reverse order (from 100 to 0 and from "A" to "F"), it doesn't seem to work...